# Run autossh on reboot through crontab

Tags: ssh, cron, pixel

I'm trying to run two command at reboot on my raspberry pi.
Here is what I tried :

```
@reboot sudo su - pi -c "screen -dm -S myscript_cron python ~/myfolder/myscript.py"
@reboot sudo su - pi -c "screen -dm -S autossh_cron autossh -M 30000 -N my_ssh_config -R 3030:localhost:3030 -C"
```

The first reboot command is working very well ! However the second one won't start.
I activated the cron logs and everything seems correct.

Thanks for your time

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that it cannot start SSH as soon as you have booted due to network connection not being established immediately

```
@reboot sleep 60; ssh user@hostname
```

For example should work

Comment: Nope it's not working either :/

Comment: Could you please add the output of the logfile

Comment: It needed a bit more than 60 sec ;) 
Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You could set wait for network connection before continuing boot, in case that is the cause. Find it in the raspi-config settings.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Boot options - Wait for network at boot.

Comment: could you give a detailed solution? 

Answer (score 0):

You can start autossh as early as you want as long as you set the `AUTOSSH_GATETIME` environment variable to 0, which will make it keep trying even if the very first connection attempt fails.

Also note that in case of using cron you probably should add the `-f` option to [push autossh to the background](https://superuser.com/a/1061127/102503). (This also automatically sets `AUTOSSH_GATETIME` to 0 as well).

Also there is absolutely no need to use `-M` other than 0. `ServerAliveInterval` + `ServerAliveCountMax` is better in basically every way (which is even said in the autossh man page itself).